# Can't add `users/sessions` routes by using devise_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I had a routes like this:

```
  devise_for :admins, path: 'admin', controllers: {sessions: 'admin/sessions'}
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  end
```

So user can be registered by using `omniauth`, but I want to enable to register by email and password. So I add users sessions like this:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions', omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
```

But the routes remains unchanged.

```
       new_admin_session GET      /admin/sign_in(.:format)                    admin/sessions#new
           admin_session POST     /admin/sign_in(.:format)                    admin/sessions#create
   destroy_admin_session DELETE   /admin/sign_out(.:format)                   admin/sessions#destroy
 user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/:provider(.:format)             users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}
  user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/:action/callback(.:format)      users/omniauth_callbacks#:action
    destroy_user_session GET      /sign_out(.:format)                         devise/sessions#destroy
```

Even `devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions'}` make route `user_omniauth_authorize` and `user_omniauth_callback`.

If I delete the line `devise_for :users`, the routes disappear also.

What am I doing wrong? I'm grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: You don't need to identify the controller the route unless you're planning to change it.  Otherwise, what you're possibly missing is `registerable` in your user model.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I wanted to know!  I forgot about `registerable`.